# what should I put in the webSocket url?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, electron, ws

I am working on a desktop chat app using electron. In order to make the chat-room work, I have to configure the websockets. My problem is that I dont know what I should put in the `const ws = new WebSocket("ws://129.0.0.1:5000");` I tried many things but I always get errors like

> failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

This is the renderer

```
const ws = new WebSocket("ws://129.0.0.1:5000");
const send_btn = document.querySelector('.send_button');
send_btn.addEventListener('click', send_data());

ws.addEventListener('open', function(event){
  ws.send('hello server');
  console.log("data sent");
});

function send_data(){
  console.log("in");
  ws.send(document.getElementById("input_text").value);

ws.on('message', function incoming(data){
  console.log(data);
})};


function quit(){
  window.close();
}
```

and this is the server.js code:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const PORT = 5000;
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({
  port: PORT
});

wss.on("connection", ws =>{
    ws.on('message', function incoming(message){
       console.log('received: ', message);
    });
    ws.send("I am sending you back!");
});

console.log("Server is liestening on port " + PORT);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server is listening to port 5000 on your localhost.
So if you want to connect to the server, you have to put either "ws://localhost:5000" or "ws://127.0.0.1:5000"

Comment: I already use ws://129.0.0.1:5000. I think the problem is on the server

Comment: I think you have a little typo here between 127 and 129..

Answer (score 0):

NVM, my problem was on main.js. I forgot to require the server. I just add

```
const server = require('./server.js');
```